# How can I break down some methods in the spring service layer

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I'm doing some maintenance/evolution on a multi-layered spring 3.0 project. The client is a heavy RCP application invoking some spring beans methods from the service layer (Managers) on a RMI based server.
I have several huge method in the Managers, some of them are doing more than 250 lines.Here is an example : (I've omitted code for clarity)

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public Declaration saveOrUpdateOrDelete(Declaration decla, List<Declaration> toDeleteList ...){

     if (decla.isNew()){

        // create from scratch and apply business rules for a creation

        manager1.compute(decla);
        dao1.save(decla);
        ...

      }else if (decla.isCopy() {

         // Copy from an other Declaration and apply business rules for a copy
         ...

       }else {

         // update Declaration
        ...
       }
     if (toDeleteList!=null){

       // Delete declarations and apply business rules for a mass delete
        ...
       }
```

The first 3 branches are mutually exclusive and represent a unit of work. The last branch (delete) can happen simultaneously with other branches.

Isn't it better to divide this method in something more 'CRUDy' for the sake of clarity and maintainability ? I've been thinking of dividing this behemoth into other manager methods like :

```
public Declaration create(Declaration decla ...){...

public Declaration update(Declaration decla ...){...

public Declaration copyFrom(Declaration decla ...){...

public void delete(List<Declaration> declaList ...){...
```

But my colleagues say it will transfer complexity and business rules to the client that I will loose the benefit of atomicity etc.. Who is right here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision what the `updateOrCreateOrWhatever` really does is made in the client anyway as it has to set the corresponding field in `Declaration` object.

The client could equally well just call the apropriate method.

That way code is definitely more manageable and testable (less branches to care about).

The only argument for maintaining it as is is the network round-trips mentioned by @Pangea. I think this could be handled by custom dispatcher class. IMO it doesn't form a part of business logic, and as such shouldn't be taken care of in service layer.

Another thing to take into consideration is transaction logic. Do create/update and deletes have to happen in the same transaction? Can both `decla` and `toDelete` be not null at the same time?

Comment: the question is are they mutually excusive? I.e. can you create AND delete records with one call? Cause that would be the only performance advantage to be gained with one-method-to-rule-them-all solution.

Comment: is there any good reason why it's done simultaneously, save for performance? i.e. do they have to be added and deleted in the same transaction?

Comment: the client interface is made of a grid Viewer  where you can update add or delete declarations. I don't think the guy who wrote this wanted to spare some network round trips, he just wrote what could be some client code inside the Manager and now It's harsh to maintain, especially when you have to deal with hibernate.

Comment: split it into separate methods then. as you say it's harsh to maintain and it probably will get worse.

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic principles to keep in mind when designing remote services is to make it coarse-grained in order to reduce network latency/round-trips. Also, after going through your code, it seems like the method encapsulates a logical unit of work as it is transactional. In this case, I suggest to keep it as it is.

However, you can still refactor it into multiple methods as long as they are not exposed to be invoked remotely thus forcing the client to manage the transactions from client layer. So make them private.

Comment: As a matter of fact this can be divided in multiple unit of work :

Comment: @webpat - then it makes sense to refactor them as separate remote methods, each one performing its own logical unit of work

Answer (score 0):

Bad design. If u really have to make the transaction atomic or complete in one trip, create a more specific method instead of having this.

What's the difference of writing:

public Object doIt(Object... obj){
...
}

Comment: Yes I agree, this is a very bad design indeed but most of my coworkers doesn't seem to notice. I'm not sure to understand your question, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: are you talking about "Do you really have to create one thing and delete it right the way?"

my bad, it was supposed to be removed. lol